# Toggle RegexOptions.IgnoreCase?

Tags: c#, regex

I have an option for the user to search with case sensitivity on or off.

Which has lead me to do dosing something like this.

```
if (ignoreCase)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) == true)
    {
        //do something with results
    }
}
else
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(data, pattern) == true)
    {
        //do something with results
    }
}
```

Is there a better way I can rewrite that? It just seems to create a lot of duplicate code for an option.

**Update**

Thinking about it would the below work? This way if I need other options I can simply control modify regexOptions?

```
RegexOptions regexOptions = new RegexOptions();
if(ignoreCase)
{
    regexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
}
if (Regex.IsMatch(data, pattern, regexOptions) == true)
{
    //do something with results
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [RegexOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is "Flags" enumeration you can just use `None` as "do not ignore case" option:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(data, pattern, 
   ignoreCase ? RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : RegexOptions.None) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I also edited my answer. Would the above work and would this work if I want to set multiple options?

Comment: @Halfwarr your edit would work, but it would be very confusing for most people reading the code - `new RegexOptions()` is indeed results in `RegexOptions.None`, but you'd rarely see `new` used for value types. If you don't like `.None` use `default(RegexOptions)` which is more common way to represent "default" of value type (which is by conventions called `None` for `Flags` enumerations).

Comment: Ok thanks in that case I'll go with your answer to avoid confusion.